# ECS fargate doesn't show up in xray

Tags: java, gradle, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-xray

So I have a kinesis consumer that is running in ECS fargate that I am trying to add on x-ray.  I have added the x-ray side car to my CloudFormation for the task definition, and it shows up in the task and is running

```
      {
        "name": "xray-daemon",
        "Image": {************.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xray-daemon},
        "cpu": 32,
        "memoryReservation": 256,
        "portMappings" : [
          {
            "containerPort": 2000,
            "protocol": "udp"
          }
        ]
      },
```

I then put before and after an SNS publish

```
AWSXRay.beginSubsegment("SNS Publish")
-- do the publish
AWSXRay.endSubsegment();
```

And still no luck.

Finally, I added the following in the start of my app to, which I beleive, is logging the entire ECS process to x-ray

```
    AWSXRayRecorderBuilder builder = AWSXRayRecorderBuilder.standard().withPlugin(new ECSPlugin())
    AWSXRay.setGlobalRecorder(builder.build())
```

So far, everything runs fine (consumer is unaffected, and running fine) but nothing is showing up in x-ray.  Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your kinesis consumer's code in a segment to be able to see any of the trace data. Segment will denote your consumer as a node in the X-Ray service map.

https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java#applications-not-using-javaxservlet-may-include-custom-interceptors-to-begin-and-end-trace-segments

Use the `AWSXRay.beginSegment` and `AWSXRay.endSegment` APIs (similar to the subsegment APIs you're already using) to create a segment around the process. Subsegments require a segment to be present. You're probably getting x-ray `ContextMissing` errors in your log while trying to create subsegment.

Comment: That seems to have been the issue!  While i didn't get a ContextMissing issue, Once I added that in, I could start seeing things in xray (under the description of the segment)

Answer (score 1):

As you add this in your app:

```
   AWSXRayRecorderBuilder builder = AWSXRayRecorderBuilder.standard().withPlugin(new ECSPlugin())
    AWSXRay.setGlobalRecorder(builder.build())
```

I'm not  expert on aws but, you didn't miss that?

> Since Fargate is a service that manages the instances your tasks run on, access to the underlying host is prohibited. Consequently, the ECSPlugin and EC2Plugins for X-Ray will not work.

If not, take a look on code snippet how you can add x-ray sdk to your app and run x-ray on fargate:

[Sending tracing information to AWS X-Ray](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-xray-fargate#sending-tracing-information-to-aws-x-ray)

Comment: I did miss that!  Well, guess i can remove that line!  Right now i am trying to add the following:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/aws-x-ray-auto-instrumentation-agent-for-java.html